# Kubernetes Nodes never scale-up

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I struggle with the weird k8s issue when I try to create new job my pod jumps into Pending State and never goes out of it.
The cluster still shows like one of the Node is working but cannot find any of them in the Nodes list.
Node Pool settings:

```
node version: 1.10.2-gke.1
min size:0
max size:2
total cores: 16CPU
total memory: 30GB
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The last line shows you requested too much CPU and RAM. It is probably the problem.

Comment: just paste Node configuration, the machine is ready for a way more than pod requested.

Comment: Problems occurs even I use default requests cpu: 100m

Comment: The scheduler can't find an appropriate node. Please provide the YAML of your job and run "kubectl describe node".
Keep in mind that the resources you assign to a node are not necessarily the resources allocatable. The node has overhead and there are system pods that need to be scheduled as well.